# R - ggplot2 parallel categorical plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with categorical longitudinal data. My data has 3 simple variables such as :

```
       id variable value
1       1        1     c
2       1        2     b
3       1        3     c
4       1        4     c
5       1        5     c
...
```

Where `variable` is basically **time**, and `value` are the 3 possible categories one `id` can take.

I am interested in producing a "parallel" longitudinal graph, similar to this with `ggplot2`

[image]

I am struggling a bit to get it right. What I came up for now is this :

```
dt0 %>% ggplot(aes(variable, value, group = id, colour = id)) +
  geom_line(colour="grey70") +
  geom_point(aes(colour=value, size = nn), size=4) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The issue with this graph is that we can't really see the "thickness" of the "transition" (the `id` lines).

I wondered if you could help me for :

a) help make visible the `id` lines, or make it "thicker" according to the number of `id` going form one state to the other

b) I also would like to `re-size` the point according to the number of `id` in this state. I tried to do it with `geom_point(aes(colour=value, size = nn), size=4)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

```
# data # 
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2) 

set.seed(10)

# generate random sequences # 
dt = as.data.frame( cbind(id = 1:1000, replicate(5, sample( c('a', 'b', 'c'), prob = c(0.1,0.2,0.7), 1000, replace = T)) ) ) 

# transform to PP file # 
dt = dt %>% melt(id.vars = c('id'))

# create a vector 1-0 if the activity was performed # 
dt0 = dt %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(variable = 1:n()) %>% arrange(id)

# create the number of people in that state # 
dt0 = dt0 %>% count(id, variable, value)
dt0 = dt0 %>% group_by(variable, value, n) %>% mutate(nn = n()) 

# to produce the first graph # 
library(vcrpart) 
otsplot(dt0$variable, factor(dt0$value), dt0$id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were so close with `geom_point(aes(colour=value, size = nn), size=4)`, the problem was that with you redefined `size` after defining it in `aes()` `ggplot` overwrote the variable reference with the constant 4. Assuming you want to use `nn` to scale line thinkness as well, you could tweak your code to this:

```
dt0 %>% ggplot(aes(variable, value, group = id, colour = id)) +
    geom_line(colour="grey70", aes(size = nn)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=value, size = nn)) + 
    scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") + theme_minimal()
```

If you wanted to use a lag value for the line thickness I would suggests adding that as a new column in `dt0`.

[image]